# Error al llamar a url desde DefaultHttpClient

Tags: android, http-post

Estoy creando una app en android y consumiendo un ws que esta en un hosting de 1&1 el problema que tengo es que cuando corro mi sentencia siempre me aparece el error de que no encuentra el documento sin embargo si copio y pego la url a la cual estoy llamando en un explorar me retorna los datos correctos.

¿Alguna idea?

```
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Error:

> ```
> Your browser can't find the document corresponding to the URL you typed in.
> ```

Comment: He buscado dicho error ya que no me resultaba conocido, no es problema de android, es de 1&1, http://www.forosdelweb.com/f19/problemas-con-1and1-681889/ intenta la solución que proponen ahi

Comment: Muchas gracias @Israel probare a ver que pasa

Comment: Un pequeño detalle: no sé como está configurado el server, pero si haces un llamado Post a una url, no es lo mismo que un llamado Get a una url. Por lo que copiar/pegar la url en el browser puede darte un resultado y llamarlo con Post puede darte otro

Comment: Ah estoy utilizando postman para testear con el metodo post, y lo probé con post y con get y están funcionando, eso fue lo que se me hizo raro...